# How to determine or calculate the correct amount of whitespace around a logo?

Tags: logo, white-space

Is there a specified way to calculate the whitespace around a logo? I have searched a lot but all I found is something like using the first word of the brand name to determine the whitespace.

Comment: Hello Smiler San, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. I took the liberty to edit it to be more legible. If I butchered anything beyond your recognition, feel free to [edit] it back by using that link or the 'edit' link under your question's text. If you have any questions about this site, and how it can be that others mangle your posts, have a look at the [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no formula for calculating what the clear space should be. It's entirely a matter of preference for whoever is designing the logo and/or style guide for the use of said logo.

For instance, if you take the GDSE logo, the clear space could be defined as the height of the text (which would be quite tight) or the height of the circle (which would be quite loose) or some other amount, all would be equally valid choices.

There is a certain amount of instinctive logic to thinking that something will look 'right' if it is the same distance from the page or box edge as it is tall, but it won't always look correct.

The reason that many people use the height of a letter or other part of the logo to define the clear space is that it is an easy way to distribute a logo with a built in measure for how to place it. There are other ways, including incorporating an invisible (transparent) box around the logo.

Decide what looks pleasant and balanced and how much space is needed to allow the logo to breath and then only use an aspect of the logo to define this measurement if it is close to the amount of space that you want anyway.

If you're struggling for inspiration then an image search for "clear space around logo" or similar will serve up lots of examples of different ways to do it.

Comment: Great answer. I would add to test the logo in various conditions. The whitespace may look fine if the logo is on its own but what if it's next to another logo that is ugly/colorful/blocky, etc.? That is likely to happen if your client sometimes sponsors events.

Answer (score 1):

I work for a publicly funded agency, which I won't name, but which has the letter "E" in its logo. Our guidance is:
"To determine the clear space, measure the width of the 'E' in the logotype. The clear space ewill change depending on the scale."

Then, we try to leave enough space to fit that letter between our logo and the edge of the frame containing it or-- between the logo and any other neighboring element.

Comment: But why the "E"? Why not one of the other characters or elements of the logo? Why use a part of the logo at all, why not say "10% of the logo's height" or some other measurement?

Answer (score 1):

I would search for the clients Brand Guidelines, this information is normally available there. Or use the prominent object in the logo for spacing around the entire logo.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I took the question as asking how to come up with that measurement (i.e. for the brand guidelines) in the first place.